# How to add Localisation to QT widgets with different language

Tags: qt, user-interface, localization

How to add `Localisation` to your project GUI in QT widgets, I mean, if I want to have a project with more than one Interface (One English and one in another language), what should I do?
In different Interface, I mean, the same objects, with different language?

Comment: Are you referring to your strings in your own code or those from the internals of Qt itself?

Comment: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/internationalization.html http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/linguist-translators.html http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/linguist-hellotr.html

Comment: @RobbieE, My own code.

Comment: Then the documentation links given by @Chernobyl should suffice.